# Color halftone to vector instead of pixels

Tags: vector, halftone

Is there a script that generates a color halftone in vectors, rather than pixels, so that every dot is a perfect circle?

Comment: Start scripting in what? For what software?

Comment: Hi @wout, if you type "halftone Illustrator" at the searching bar there are many answers about this subject.

Comment: [**VectorRaster**](https://lostminds.com/vectoraster7/) I don't know how "perfect" the circles are, but it does what you describe.

Comment: [**Phantasm**](https://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/) from Astute Graphics will also convert to a vector halftone effect

Comment: @Danielillo No, I would need the individual circles as described in my question. Tracing a bitmap is the obvious answer and I would not have come here with such a simple question.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, your suggestions are very much what I am looking for. I would have preferred something less reliant on Adobe products, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: @wout you can do this in Inkscape (which is free and works on linux). There's a [tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/z4fLHKSsCy4) - no scripting is required,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[VectorRaster](https://lostminds.com/vectoraster7/)** is a stand alone application designed to input a raster image, convert to a halftone effect, then spit out a vector EPS or PDF. No direct need for any Adobe application.

**[Phantasm](https://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/)** from Astute Graphics is an Adobe Illustrator Plug-in that pretty much does the same thing within Illustrator. Phantasm offers more on-the-fly WYSIWYG control over the conversion as well as the ability to create halftones using special or unusual shapes for the "dots". There's really a *great deal* more control over the conversion in Phantasm, not merely a couple options.

I have both. I personally prefer Phantasm... but I'm a long standing Illustrator user as well.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Unfortunately, Illustrator is not an option for me as I am on Linux. VectorRaster I can probably use in a virtual machine, or on the Mac of my partner.

Comment: @wout: if you include your current OS and for what software you are scripting into your question, you might get more relevant answers.